# If Else Shortcode Condition to include or exclude pages ID

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement, shortcode

I have this code, got it from someone on the internet

```
  function if_statement($atts, $content = null) {
    if (empty($atts)) return '';
        
    $callable = array_shift($atts);
    if (is_callable($callable)) {
      $condition = (boolean)call_user_func_array($callable, $atts);
    } else {
       throw new Excaption('First argument must be callable!');
    }
   
    $else = '[else]';
    
    if (strpos($content, $else) !== false) {
      list($if, $else) = explode($else, $content, 2);
    } else {
      $if = $content;
      $else = "";
    }
        
    return do_shortcode($condition ? $if : $else);
  }
 
  // register shortcode
  add_shortcode('if', 'if_statement');
```

This is what it does

```
[if is_user_logged_in]
You are already logged in. Please use the menu to select proper option.
[else]
Display registration form.
[/if]
```

My question is that how can I make this function perform a hide/show to pages using is_page() / or any so that it would be like this

```
[if show_on_page="3,4"]
Please show this on the pages ID 3 & 4
[else]
while this one will show on every other pages excluding 3 & 4
[/if]
```

so this means that I the first will show on pages 3 & 4 and the else will show to every page except 3 & 4, hope this make sense....

I have this current code now and it is still not working on my end

```
if (!function_exists('array_key_first')) {
    function array_key_first(array $arr) {
        foreach($arr as $key => $unused) {
            return $key;
        }
        return NULL;
    }
} // for Php 7.2

add_shortcode( 'if', 'if_statement' );
function if_statement( $atts, $content = null ){
    //global $whitelisted_functions;
    
    $whitelisted_functions = array(
        'is_page',
    );
    
    
    if (empty($atts)) return '';
    
    $first_key = array_key_first($atts);
    

    if( is_callable($first_key) ){
        // You have a `function="1,2,3"` setup
        $callable = $first_key;

        $args = explode(',', $atts[$first_key] );
        $args = array_map( function($v){
            return is_numeric($v) ? absint($v) : strval($v);
        }, $args);
    } else {
        // You are calling a function with no args
        $callable = array_shift($atts);
    }

    if( !in_array($callable, $whitelisted_functions) )
        throw new Exception('Function must be whitelisted');

    if( is_callable($callable) ){
        $condition = (boolean) call_user_func( $callable, $args );
    } else {
        throw new Exception('First argument must be callable!');
    }

    $else = '[else]';

    if( strpos($content, $else) !== false) {
        list($if, $else) = explode($else, $content, 2);
    } else {
        $if = $content;
        $else = "";
    }
            
    return do_shortcode( $condition ? $if : $else );
}
```

This code is from @Xhynk see current answer

Answer (score 0):

Oh man, this is a pretty creative solution. It's not how I'd handle it personally (I'd bake it all into the functionality of the shortcode directly on the PHP side) - *however* I can absolutely see a use-case for this (giving content editors an easier ability to *see* the output of an if/else statement and the like. So with that said, let's get started.

First and Foremost:

#### You should create a whitelist of functions that you're allowing to be callable!

Right now, anybody who can write a post on your site can pass **any** WordPress of PHP function, and your site will parse and handle it. They can do `[if phpinfo]` and it will dump out ALL of the semi-sensitive server stats that you *probably* don't want exposed. You should absolutely be creating a list of functions that are useable.

```
$whitelisted_functions = array(
    'is_page',
    'is_user_logged_in',
);

function if_statement($atts, $content = null) {
    // blah blah blah
    global $whitelisted_functions;
    if( in_array($callable, $whitelisted_functions){
        // Callable is safe, according to you.
    }
}
```

Please please please implement something like that to make sure only functions you **want** runnable, are runnable. [`call_user_func()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php) and [`call_user_func_array()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php) are fantastic functions, but they get a bad rap because the function (and argument) strings passed to them are all-too-often left unsanitized and unvalidated.

With that out of the way, this is absolutely possible. The first thing you'll want to notice is that the [`add_shortcode()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_shortcode) function will pass the attributes along as a `key => value` pair. If you're using `function="value1,value2="` it gets passed as `["function"] => ["value1,value2"]`. If you're using `function` without any parameters, it gets passed as `[0] => ["function"]`, so before you use [`array_shift()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php), you'll probably want to use [`array_key_first()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-first.php) (or if you're not using PHP 7.3 or newer, `reset($atts); $first_key = key($atts);` to check the first key and see if it's a callable function.

From there, you can use [`explode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) the `$atts` and use [`array_map()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) to parse out the arguments or otherwise sanitize them however you want. If it wasn't callable, it means it's probably `0`, so *then* you can `array_shift` to get it.

Again, this is where you'd want to have a *white list of callable functions*

You can also replace [`call_user_func_array()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php) with [`call_user_func()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php) (and then fix the typo in `throw new Excaption`)

I'm not sure if you should keep using [`do_shortcode()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_shortcode) or if you should be calling [`apply_filters()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/apply_filters) with [`the_content`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/the_content) filter at the end though, so I'll leave it as it is.

Lastly, I'm not sure you want to `throw exception` when dealing with content relatable issues, so you may consider just `return "Function not callable/whitelisted"` instead, preventing the function from calling, and the site from experiencing a fatal error. But since you have that, I'll leave it as-is.

In the end, you'd end up with something like this:

```
add_shortcode( 'if', 'if_statement' );
function if_statement( $atts, $content = null ){
    global $whitelisted_functions;
    if (empty($atts)) return '';
    
    $first_key = array_key_first($atts);
    if( is_callable($first_key) ){
        // You have a `function="1,2,3"` setup
        $callable = $first_key;

        $args = explode(',', $atts[$first_key] );
        $args = array_map( function($v){
            return is_numeric($v) ? absint($v) : strval($v);
        }, $args);
    } else {
        // You are calling a function with no args
        $callable = array_shift($atts);
    }

    if( !in_array($callable, $whitelisted_functions) )
        throw new Exception('Function must be whitelisted');

    if( is_callable($callable) ){
        $condition = (boolean) call_user_func( $callable, $args );
    } else {
        throw new Exception('First argument must be callable!');
    }

    $else = '[else]';

    if( strpos($content, $else) !== false) {
        list($if, $else) = explode($else, $content, 2);
    } else {
        $if = $content;
        $else = "";
    }
            
    return do_shortcode( $condition ? $if : $else );
}
```

You can see a few examples here:

- https://xhynk.com/content-mask/so-65729818-answer/
- https://xhynk.com/content-mask/so-65729818-answer-2/
- https://xhynk.com/content-mask/so-65729818-answer-3/

These are using:

```
[if is_page="1762,1757"]
This is page 1757 or 1762.
[else]
This isn't one of the pages passed along.
[/if]
```

Here's one for your [`is_user_logged_in()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_user_logged_in) check:

- https://xhynk.com/content-mask/so-65729818-answer-4/

And here's one trying to call [`phpinfo()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php) which WOULD work, but since it's not in the `$whitelisted_functions` array, it throws the exception (this also showcases why you may consider returning a string with the error message instead of throwing an exception:

- https://xhynk.com/content-mask/so-65729818-answer-5

---

#### Documentation & Function Reference

| Function | Linked Description |
| --- | --- |
| `the_content` | [Filters the post content.](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/the_content) |
| `is_user_logged_in()` | [Determines whether the current visitor is a logged in user.](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_user_logged_in) |
| `explode()` | [Split a string by a string](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) |
| `array_key_first()` | [Gets the first key of an array](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-first.php) |
| `array_map()` | [Applies the callback to the elements of the given arrays](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) |
| `array_shift()` | [Shift an element off the beginning of array](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php) |
| `call_user_func_array()` | [Call a callback with an array of parameters](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php) |
| `add_shortcode()` | [Adds a new shortcode.](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_shortcode) |
| `do_shortcode()` | [Search content for shortcodes and filter shortcodes through their hooks.](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_shortcode) |
| `call_user_func()` | [Call the callback given by the first parameter](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php) |
| `phpinfo()` | [Outputs information about PHP's configuration](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php) |
| `apply_filters()` | [Calls the callback functions that have been added to a filter hook.](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/apply_filters) |

Comment: Hi @Xhynk thank you for this answer, I have tried adding the code but there seems to be an error "Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function array_key_first() "

Comment: Oh sorry about that, `array_key_first` requires PHP 7.3 or greater. Without it you'll need to use something like `reset($atts); $first_key = key($atts);`

Comment: is it ok that I added the $whitelisted_functions = array('is_page','is_user_logged_in',); inside the function and deleted the global $whitelisted_functions;

Comment: It should be perfectly fine! I just had it that way in because I wasn't sure what your file structure looked like - as long as you have an accessible array of white listed functions, you should be good to go. Thinking of expandability, you could even turn it into a function and get a different list of functions based on user role, logged in state, etc

Comment: Hi there, sorry but I am currently using your code and I still cant get it to work.

Comment: the problem is that it does not what page ID am I at, it treats every page the same [if is_page="1762"]